# Properly Using Firebase Cloud Functions and Stripe

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, stripe-payments, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use Firebase Cloud functions and Stripe, and iOS (Swift). I want to use Firebase Cloud functions to perform the card charge as is required by Stripe. I am trying to use this example: [Firebase Stripe Example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe)

I uploaded the example they gave, but I need to modify the charge function slightly. I tried setting it to the file path I have in my real time data base, but I am not sure how to modify the entire thing so that It will work off of my realtime database structure. Such as grabbing the parameters it needs. Here is what my structure looks like: [image: Database Structure for Stripe charges.] after the Payments node is the userID.

I know that the function basically looks for database updates to the specific node, but I am not sure how to make sure it grabs the correct values from the child nodes. I hope I have described this in an understandable way. If I haven't let me know and I will do my best to reword. Thank you!

Comment: using the key ending with Bb2 you can get snapshot of all he details under it and use your payment array from snapshot

Comment: or what do you basically want to fetch and what value do you have to make a query to FirebaseDB

Comment: @iOSGeek Stripe requires, the amount, the currency type, and the token they send you. https://stripe.com/docs/charges So I guess  I need to grab those items, but I haven't used javascript before so I am not sure what it all means. I could read the documentation, but I still don't know they syntax etc..

Comment: so to access Stripe you need the value stored under paymentID ? amount and token value

Comment: yes, they need the amount and the token, because that is the key they send you and then you use your back end to send it back so the charge can be processed along with the parameters needed. I am just not sure if I have to name my nodes specifically etc..

Comment: okay I can get you your amount and Token in payment id in a string

Comment: Does that mean you are going to post a solution?

Comment: Do you have this Value stored Bb2 to get snapshot  ?

Comment: I’m sorry I  don’t understand your question.

Comment: key value under Payments Tab BzLzB73fw..Bb2 is this userId ? if it is do you know this value at runtime or its an autogeneratedchild key ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149542/discussion-between-ios-geek-and-taylor-simpson).

Comment: Hi @TaylorSimpson, can you share with me how exactly did you make it work. Especially the cloud function part.  I'm struggling to do it!!! Thank you!

Comment: @John, which part are you stuck on exactly?

Comment: Thank for your answer @TaylorSimpson, The cloud function backend is working and firebase is saving the stripe_customers id to the database, but no customer is being created in my Stripe dashboard. Do I need to create the stripe customer in my swift project. I'm just a little bit confuse because it's my first time using it, and solving this problem will be a huge milestone in my project. Tell me if you are willing to chat. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I'm not sure, in my project I make the user enter their card every time, so I haven't created stripe users.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Alright guys I figured it out myself and I will write a mini tutorial here.

Because this question specifically deals with stripe I will only cover this specific use case. First it is important to read the Stripe documentation. It specifies the parameters it is expecting you to give to it's api. Here is the link for what is expected when you charge a card with Stripe: [Stripe Charges Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/charges)

Second you need to model your Firebase Realtime database after those expected parameters, at least in regards to the purchases a user will make in your app. Most of the time you can use a dictionary with Key:value pairs. Make sure you multiply your amount parameter by 100 as Stripe only takes integers. This means if you you are charging 22.48 for example then you multiply it by 100 to get 2248. When you check your dashboard in stripe it will show up as 22.48.

Third Stripe needs to talk to a back end so that you can charge the card. Firebase Cloud functions are perfect for this. Remember your real time database? Well you can trigger a Cloud function when a write occurs on a node that you specify. Luckily Firebase has provided a sample on GitHub: [Firebase Stripe Example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/stripe/functions/index.js)

You can modify the line of code where it listens for a write to the data base. You can change it to your structure specifically as long as you return at least the token and the amount to be charged. If you are going to make the user enter their information every time, then you need to delete the customer parameter (in the index.js file) as it will expect a different token with a different prefix. (This is noted in the documentation) The rest of the example is well documented and can be followed. The outcome of the charge will be written back into your database. The following video shows you how Functions triggered on write work and some of the nomenclature used. : [Youtube Video for Cloud Functions triggered on write.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7E13ZBCyKT0)

I hope this helps a few of you as I know questions about stripe and firebase are fairly common.

Comment: So basically they register the amount as pennies?

Comment: would you mind sharing a snippet of your database where amount/token/etc are being written as well as a snippet of your 'create charge' function on firebase?

Comment: Yeah, I’ll do that. It might be a few days tho. I’m currently on my way to a youth retreat so I don’t have access to my development machine right now. But I might when I arrive.

Comment: Thanks! Server wise I think I got it working but it's returning an error on my client side

Comment: @cyril If you tell me the error I may be able to just tell you what needs to be done.

Comment: @TaylorSimpson I was getting an error about not setting customer or something along those lines but I finally figured things out. Thanks!