# How to setup Stripe payments in a Firebase iOS/Swift application without node or heroku?

Tags: swift, firebase, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am currently building a Swift application, using Firebase as my backend, and would like to integrate payments (user <--> user) in the app.  From what I've seen, Firebase does not provide any iOS/Swift documentation on how to integrate Stripe using their SDK.  I have been going through their docs and have not found anything quite that helpful yet.

I am curious whether anyone here has successfully developed a Swift app that uses Firebase and Stripe together (esp. without having to use node or Heroku).  Is this even currently possible with Firebase?

Any advice much appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386361/is-it-possible-to-integrate-stripe-with-firebase-and-with-ios

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45900138/using-cloud-functions-for-firebase-as-my-backend-for-implementing-stripe-in-ios

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45180346/properly-using-firebase-cloud-functions-and-stripe